# Is there @font-face support in gmail — via iOS Mail

Tags: email, gmail, font-face, webfonts

I was hoping someone might know whether @font-face will be supported for gmail accounts when viewed via the iOS Mail app.

Gmail doesn't support @font-face, whereas iOS Mail does, but I can't find any info on which would take precedence in this scenario.

Any pointers on this would be much appreciated.

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gmail does not support `@font-face` in any version (iOS, Android, desktop webmail), as reported by [Can I Email](https://www.caniemail.com/features/css-at-font-face/).

[image: Can I email… @font-face]

So you can only use in Gmail:

- Fonts installed on your device. Either installed by default by your operating system, by a third party app or by yourself.
- Fonts embedded by the app itself. For example, in Gmail desktop webmail, you can use Roboto and Google Sans.